# how to ssh using jumphost, without using a tunnel

Tags: ssh

I have the following servers:

- My localhost (`localhost`)
- A Jumphost (`jumphost`)
- A server accessible only through jumphost (`finalhost`)

I can run the following command

```
ssh -t user@jumphost ssh -t user@finalhost
```

To connect to `finalhost` from `localhost`. The connection from `jumphost` to `finalhost` is authenticated using `gssapi-with-mic`, and from `localhost` to `jumphost` with password.

What is the equivalent `ssh_config` I need to use so that I can do

```
ssh finalhost
```

or

```
scp file finalhost:/some/path/
```

from `localhost` and be connected?

The normal use of `proxycommand`

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W finalhost:22 user@jumphost' user@finalhost
```

does not work, as it tries to authenticate to `finalhost` using my `localhost`.

Comment: *does not work, as it tries to authenticate to finalhost using my localhost.* ... that is right. You don't want to copy your private keys fo the jumpbox.

Comment: localhost does not have any private keys for finalhost, but jumphost does... and I have a password for jumphost. So what I want is for jumphost's private key to be used (well, to be accurate, jumphost to finalhost is gssapi-with-mic, not private key)

Comment: It is not possible if you want to authenticate from the second host. It is not jumpbox, but bastion.

Comment: Simply chaining 2 SSH commands works though... Is there no option to replicate that in ssh_config? It doesn't have to be ProxyCommand, any other option would do as well.

Comment: Exactly. There is no alternative dor ssh config. Only chance is bash alias or function as a "shortcut"

Comment: @Jakuje  Ok... An alias will work for SSH.. is there some syntax that can be used for scp? If so you can add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set up bastion "jumpbox" in ssh configuration, where you need the second hop authentication to be initiated from the bastion.

Your only chance is to use bash aliases or functions to simplify local commands.

Unfortunately, there I so simple way to use scp in this case.